# Почему не работает проверка if?

Tags: java, android

У меня простой вопрос, но я чет делаю не так.
Приложение работает с БД и при открытии `activity` сохраняет инфу из БД в `array`, а из `array` выводит инфу в `listview`. Так вот каждый раз при открытии этого `activity` вызывается метод `onCreate` и естественно каждый раз при открытии одна и та же инфа сохраняется в `array` и естественно дублируется в `listview`. Я написал простую проверка "флаг" она вроде называется, но она почему то не работает и каждый раз список одних и тех же `item` в `listview` становиться все больше...

Вот код :

```
public class ListOfMyWords extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressDialogClass dialog;
private MyAdapterForWords adapterForWords;


  private boolean wasUpdate; //<=====


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_my_words);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvOfMyWords);
    adapterForWords = new MyAdapterForWords(getApplicationContext());
    lv.setAdapter(adapterForWords);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new EditAndDelete());

    dialog = new ProgressDialogClass(this);


     if (!wasUpdate) { //<=====
        saveFromParse();
    }


}

private void saveFromParse() {

    dialog.showProgressDialog();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> pq = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyDictionary");
            pq.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
                            Word word = new Word(
                                    list.get(index).getString("hebrewWord"),
                                    list.get(index).getString("wordTranslation"),
                                    list.get(index).getString("wordTranslate"),
                                    list.get(index).getString("objectID"));
                            SingletonForWords.getSingletonForWords().getArrayWords().add(word);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sorry",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }



                    wasUpdate = true; //<=====



                    dialog.hideProgressDialog();
                    adapterForWords.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Во первых, создавать новый поток здесь не нужно, т.к. название метода `findInBackground` говорит о том, что работа и так выполняется в отдельном потоке, и результат приходит в callback `done`.

Во вторых, при создании активити, создается новый экземпляр класса, следовательно всем полям класса присваиваются [значения по умолчанию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), если не определено явное инициализирование полей. Для типа `boolean` значением по умолчанию является `false`. Поэтому и происходит загрузка данных при старте активити. Отсюда ваша проверка флага выглядит абсолютно бесполезной. Выходом из этой ситуации может стать сохранение данных например в бд, а при старте смотреть есть ли данные или нет, и если их нет то загружать.

В третьих, давайте методам, классам, переменным имена, которые смогут дать ответ на вопрос - "Что делает этот метод/класс/...?". Это может избавить от части комментариев, т.к. из названия будет понятно для чего это нужно. Ваш метод `saveFromParse` предполагает какое то сохранение, хотя на самом деле он что-то загружает.

Ну и в четвертых, никогда не создавайте явно `Thread`, используйте хотя бы `AsyncTask`, хотя и его лучше заменить на что-то получше. Иначе это приведет к утечкам, непонятным ошибкам, неправильной работе и т.д.

Comment: Я еще не сталкивался с `AsyncTask` , сейчас почитаю.

Comment: А насчет кода по проверке, у меня загружается инфа с БД в `array`, тогда исходя из вашего совета, нужно проверить, есть ли в `array` что то или нет. Но как проверить это? можете показать на примере кода?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko если список типа ```List```, то у него есть метод ```isEmpty``` который вернет ```true``` если список пуст - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty()